# Is it possible to merge two pandas dataframes based on indices and column names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
left = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "Col": ["D", "C", "B", "A"],
        },
        index=[0, 1, 2, 3],
    )
right = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
            "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
            "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
            "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],
        },
        index=[0, 1, 2, 3],
    )
```

Is it possible to merge them based on indices and `col` of the left and column names on the right ?

I need to get the following result:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "Col": ["D", "C", "B", "A"],
            "Val": ["D0", "C1", "B2", "A3"],
        },
    )
```

Comment: Weird that `right.loc[left.index, left['Col']]` doesn't do it. I'm used to numpy's index broadcasting rules

Comment: `np.diag` over what the above comment says is also an option. might be slow

Comment: @MustafaAydın. I don't like the idea of computing N^2 items just to get N of them, but sure, it would work

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, slow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
left['new'] = right.values[np.arange(len(left)), right.columns.get_indexer(left.Col)]
left
Out[129]: 
  Col new
0   D  D0
1   C  C1
2   B  B2
3   A  A3
```

Notice, we used to have `lookup` but it deprecated, ,above is one of the alternative of `lookup` from `numpy`

The reason here I am not use the `index` : `numpy` do not have index, so we need the position to pass by the correct value, most of time index same as position but it will may different from
each other as well.

Comment: `right.values[left.index.get_indexer(left.index), right.columns.get_indexer(left.Col)]` would not rely on the index being in ascending order

Comment: @MadPhysicist may be `right.values[right.index.get_indexer(left.index), right.columns.get_indexer(left.Col)]` ? If the left indices are not unique ?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```py
left["new"] = right.apply(lambda x: x[left.loc[x.name, "Col"]], axis=1)
print(left)
```

Prints:

```
  Col new
0   D  D0
1   C  C1
2   B  B2
3   A  A3
```

Comment: thanks. Just measured - `apply` is much slower than the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach (convert columns to index with `melt` and then `merge`):

```
left['id'] = left.index    
m = right.melt(ignore_index=False, var_name="Col", value_name="Val")
m['id'] = m.index    
result = pd.merge(left, m, on=["id", "Col"])[["Col", "Val"]]
```

It is faster than use of `apply` but slower than the accepted answer.